# How do you set the stack order of the series in a stacked bar chart?

Tags: highcharts

I have been able to control the stacking order of highchart by setting the `index` field in the series objects like this:

```
            series: [
                {
                    name: 'My Products',
                    data: randomRange(12, 7, 61), // Just random test data for now.
                    stack: 'ProductType',
                    index: 1 // Here index sets the stacking order in the bar.  This will be on the bottom.
                }, {
                    name: 'Total',
                    data: randomRange(12, 233, 240), // Just random test data for now.
                    stack: 'ProductType',
                    index: 0 // This will be on the top.
                }
            ]
```

As you can see, a lower index number will be stacked higher in the bar.

[image]

Now I am trying to refresh the series, but the stacking order gets lost and I cannot set the index:

```
            var chart1 = $('#quantityPerMonthChart1').highcharts();
            chart1.series[1].setData(randomRange(12, 233, 240), false);
            chart1.series[1].index = 0;  // Doesn't work.
            chart1.series[0].setData(randomRange(12, 7, 61), false);
            chart1.series[0].index = 1;  // Doesn't work.
            chart1.redraw();
```

Comment: If you want the stack index inversed you can use: `yAxis: { reversedStacks: true }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seemed to be no documentation or other examples on the net on how to do this.  So I experimented and found out that the index is set **naturally** by the order in which you add to the series array.  So I could change my *seed* series to this:

```
            series: [
                {
                    name: 'Total', // The series you add first will get stacked on the top
                    data: randomRange(12, 233, 240),
                    stack: 'ProductType'
                }, {
                    name: 'My Products',
                    data: randomRange(12, 7, 61),
                    stack: 'ProductType'
                }
            ]
```

Then when I refresh the chart data with different options, I do this:

```
        $('#productType').on('change', function() {
            var chart1 = $('#quantityPerMonthChart1').highcharts();
            // These series already have an index (which affects stack order).  
            // Here it is unchanged.
            chart1.series[0].setData(randomRange(12, 233, 240), false);
            chart1.series[1].setData(randomRange(12, 7, 61), false);
            chart1.redraw();
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

`index` is option of a series that can be update using [`Series.update()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update) - it can be also used to update data of the series as data is another option.

```
$(function() {
  var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      type: 'column'
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        stacking: 'normal'
      }
    },
    series: [{
      data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4],
      index: 1
    }, {
      data: [6, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4],
      index: 2,
      id: 's2'
    }]
  });

  $('#button').click(function() {
        chart.get('s2').update({index: 0});
  });
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ae7Ljmc7/

Comment: @Kacper Can you tell me how we can do this on chartLoad? i tried updating series indexes on chartLoad, i get a maximum call stack error when the chart renders. Is it possible to update multiple series indexes on chartLoad?

Comment: If you want to change indexes on chart load then it means that chart configuration should be different to start with and no update will be required. It would be easier to process data before using in a chart and set indexes in chart configuration to keep initial animation, but here's the demo you requested: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/anj1g37x/